# How to edit posts/pages without making the change live?

Tags: database, migration, draft, revisions

We have a situation here at work I've never run into in many years of working with Wordpress.

In the past, it's been acceptable to edit a post or page, click update, and make the changes live on the site.

However, in this case, we need to edit posts/pages and preview these changes but *not* actually make said changes live until they are reviewed or perhaps not until a certain date (as to comply with an embargo).

This is obviously not an issue with NEW content, as of course we can simply save as Draft.  I was wondering about EDITS to content already live.

I realize I can create 2 identical Wordpress installs and then migrate the entire database from the "dev" server to the "live" server, but I was wondering if there's a better process and/or software to manage which version/revision of a post is the "live" one.

I would imagine that this is a common need in CMS situations, no?  What do other users do?

Comment: You can create duplicate as a draft and when the time come to switch between. or you can make the changes and save them and then go back with the revision and then you get a revision with the new update so you could switch later.

Comment: I think there is the possibility for other post statuses, such as "pending" or "pending review", I have seen this implemented by some plugins before. eg. editflow